# How do I show EmptyDataText only after the user submits the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-4.0

I just created a basic ASP.NET website using [Microsoft's walkthrough here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw738475.aspx). It has one page with a form that takes in some text input, runs a database query based on that, and results the results in a `GridView`. I added the [`EmptyDataText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to my `GridView` to explicitly show users when their search returns no results.

It all works as expected with one exception:

IIS shows my `EmptyDataText` of "No results found." even *before* the search form is submitted.

This defeats my purpose behind using `EmptyDataText`, which is to indicate to the user that the webpage successfully submitted their search but found no results, as opposed to took their search and threw it into the ether.

For example, a user who searches for something that cannot be found will see "No results found." both before and after their search, as opposed to nothing before and "No results found." after. The former behavior gives the impression that the search didn't work.

How can I configure my `GridView` to show the `EmptyDataText` only *after* the search form is submitted?

Comment: Are you databinding your gridview before the search has taken place?

Comment: @Jeremy - How can I tell? I mostly created this off of the Microsoft walkthrough, so I barely know what I'm doing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers suggested, the `GridView` is being bound before the user makes a search because it has a `DataSourceID` attribute. As explained [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), this attribute causes the `GridView` to automatically bind to the specified source:

> To bind to a data source control, set the DataSourceID property of the GridView control to the ID value of the data source control. The GridView control automatically binds to the specified data source control and can take advantage of the data source control's capabilities to perform sorting, updating, deleting, and paging. This is the preferred method to bind to data.

To get the behavior I was looking for, I removed that attribute from the `GridView` and instead added an `OnClick` attribute to the submit button for my search form. The `OnClick` attribute refers to a method `BindGridView` that gets called only when the user submits the form.

All this method does is populate the `DataSourceID` with the same value it had before as an attribute:

```
public void BindGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSourceID = "DataSourceID1";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using **sqldatasource** that will bind automatically while loading the page. Bind the gridview programatically while clicking the search button

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind your GridView until after the user has initiated a search.  When you bind your GridView with a datasource that has 0 records, then the `EmptyDataText` will be displayed.

Chances are that you are binding it on Page_Load.

**EDIT**

Wherever a DataBind() is performed in your code (other than the action handler), remove it.  Your DataBind() should only occur in the handler that receives the user action.

If Visual Studio is doing some voodoo behind the scenes with automatic binding, you can always default the grid to invisible.  Make it visible when the user initiates a search.

Comment: The `Page_Load` function for the search page only calls one function that sets focus to the search input. Commenting it out doesn't change the behavior of the `GridView`.

Comment: I can't find any calls to `DataBind()` in my solution, but I do have calls to `DataBinder.Eval()` as I commented on pOcHa's answer. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: Heh :) OK, I replaced all my `TemplateField`s with `BoundFields`, which do not include any calls to `DataBinder.Eval()`. The `EmptyDataText` still shows. I will try making the grid visible on form submission as you just suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't databind it **before** the search, it will effectively be completely invisible until then.

**UPDATE:** maybe you are using a DataSourceID (which databinds automatically)?

**UPDATE 2:** First off, for what ever reason was the downvote (at least have a decency to leave a comment)? If it weren't for me the OP would still not have known where the problem lies - and secondly, just remove the `DataSourceID` property from the declaration, and set it back from codebehind when the user makes a search (you might want to call the `GridView DataBind()` method manually after that, but only if it doesn't do that on its own - try it without first).

Comment: I do call `DataBinder.Eval()` inside a `TemplateField` in the `GridView`. I do that so I can call a function that highlights certain strings in the output. Would that bind the grid to the data source before the form is submitted?

Comment: Just tested it and the answer is no.

Comment: @NickChammas no, that only databinds controls inside **when** you databind the GridView itself - are you sure you are not calling the DataBind() method **and** not using a DataSourceId property on the GridView?

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay attention to that. Yes, the `GridView` does have a `DataSourceID` property. Are you suggesting I bind this grid to its source without this property? How do I do that?

Comment: @NickChammas I edited the answer for you... and don't forget to accept an answer it if helped you

Comment: This answer was helpful so I upvoted it. I will be providing my own answer with the details of what I did.